# CSS Nesting Not Getting Expected

Tags: html, css, button, nested

I'm new to HTML/CSS so this may be a stupid/basic question, but I legitimately cannot find the answer to why this is happening:

I am making a super-basic webpage where there are buttons in the navigation bar that change the image that is displayed in the content section. I just want to change the appearance of the buttons but seem to be unable to do so:

HTML doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle.css">
    <script src='navfunc.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- WRAPPER DIV -->
<div id='wrapper'>

<!-- HEADER DIV -->
<div class = 'header'>
<h1> Price History and Stock Data </h1>

</div>

<!-- SIDEBAR/NAV DIV -->
<div class = 'sidebar'>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('AMBA')"> AMBA </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('APH')"> APH </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('ASX')"> ASX </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('B')"> B </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('BDS')"> BDSI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNC')"> CNC </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNK')"> CNK </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('COLB')"> COLB </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('EWBC')"> EWBC </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('FB')"> FB </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('GPRO')"> GPRO </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HAIN')"> HAIN </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HEI')"> HEI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('LCI')"> LCI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('MANU')"> MANU </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('NCLH')"> NCLH </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('RCL')"> RCL </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSN')"> TSN </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSO')"> TSO </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('WWD')"> WWD </button> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</div>

<!-- CONTENT DIV -->
<div class = 'content'>
<img id='hmap' src = 'AMBA_heatmap.png' alt='AMBA', style="width: 880px; height: 660px;">

</div>

<!-- FOOTER DIV -->
<div class = 'footer'>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Doc:

```
/* WRAPPER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1280px;
}

/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.header{
    background-color: #87CEFA;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Sans-Serif ;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #286F02;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/* SIDEBAR ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.sidebar{
    float: left;
    height: 1024px;
    width: 225px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color: #0F4FAF; /* Blue*/

}

div.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px
}
div.sidebar ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
}


nav.sidebar button {
    background-color: '#4CAF50'; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 95px;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* CONTENT ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.content {
    width: 910px;
    height: 1024px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border: 2px solid #0F0F0F;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
    margin:1px;
    padding:5px;
}

/* FOOTER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.footer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The center of attention in these docs is just the nav bar section where i write:

```
div.sidebar button {
    background-color: '#4CAF50'; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 95px;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

But the buttons still take on default button values.
I messed around with it a little and got some styles to change in the browser but then if i changed them again or changed them back, they stopped working...

Sorry if this is kinda vague, but I'm under the impression that there is something fundamental that I'm missing and can't seem to figure out what it is.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nav.sidebar button` will select all descendant button elements of a nav element with the class sidebar. You want `div.sidebar > nav button`. This will select all buttons that are descendants of all nav elements that are a child of divs with the class sidebar.

```css
/* WRAPPER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1280px;
}

/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.header{
    background-color: #87CEFA;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Sans-Serif ;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #286F02;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/* SIDEBAR ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.sidebar{
    float: left;
    height: 1024px;
    width: 225px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color: #0F4FAF; /* Blue*/

}

div.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px
}
div.sidebar ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
}


div.sidebar > nav button {
    background-color: '#4CAF50'; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 95px;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* CONTENT ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.content {
    width: 910px;
    height: 1024px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border: 2px solid #0F0F0F;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
    margin:1px;
    padding:5px;
}

/* FOOTER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.footer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- WRAPPER DIV -->
<div id='wrapper'>

  <!-- HEADER DIV -->
  <div class='header'>
    <h1> Price History and Stock Data </h1>

  </div>

  <!-- SIDEBAR/NAV DIV -->
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('AMBA')">AMBA</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('APH')">APH</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('ASX')">ASX</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('B')">B</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('BDS')">BDSI</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNC')">CNC</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNK')">CNK</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('COLB')">COLB</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('EWBC')">EWBC</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('FB')">FB</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('GPRO')">GPRO</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HAIN')">HAIN</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HEI')">HEI</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('LCI')">LCI</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('MANU')">MANU</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('NCLH')">NCLH</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('RCL')">RCL</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSN')">TSN</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSO')">TSO</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('WWD')">WWD</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <!-- CONTENT DIV -->
  <div class='content'>
    <img id='hmap' src='AMBA_heatmap.png' alt='AMBA' , style="width: 880px; height: 660px;">

  </div>

  <!-- FOOTER DIV -->
  <div class='footer'>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry i miss typed my entry- it is corrected now. What I actually wrote was div.sidebar button (not nav.sidebar button since there is no nav with class sidebar)

Comment: Ahh gotcha, it worked with div.sidebar > nav button. But out of curiosity, why does it need div.sidebar > NAV button instead of just div.sidebar button?

Comment: But you see it working in the example in my answer though right? If that doesn't correct your issue then you probably have more CSS that you haven't shared.

Comment: yes your solution worked (i mis-typed first time), but  I'm still confused on the use of '>' and why i had to specify 'nav' before button.... ?

Comment: You don't really need to have `nav` in there. It just makes it more specific so that the rule isn't applied to other elements you may have. `div.sidebar button` should work too.

Comment: gotcha. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in your css:

```
.sidebar>nav button {
background-color: '#4CAF50'; /* Green */
border: none;
color: white;
width: 95px;
padding: 10px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
```

}

```css
/* WRAPPER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1280px;
}

/* HEADER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.header{
    background-color: #87CEFA;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Sans-Serif ;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #286F02;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

/* SIDEBAR ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.sidebar{
    float: left;
    height: 1024px;
    width: 225px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color: #0F4FAF; /* Blue*/

}

div.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px
}
div.sidebar ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
}


.sidebar>nav button {
    background-color: '#4CAF50'; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 95px;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* CONTENT ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.content {
    width: 910px;
    height: 1024px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border: 2px solid #0F0F0F;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
    margin:1px;
    padding:5px;
}

/* FOOTER ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div.footer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle.css">
    <script src='navfunc.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- WRAPPER DIV -->
<div id='wrapper'>

<!-- HEADER DIV -->
<div class = 'header'>
<h1> Price History and Stock Data </h1>

</div>

<!-- SIDEBAR/NAV DIV -->
<div class = 'sidebar'>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('AMBA')"> AMBA </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('APH')"> APH </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('ASX')"> ASX </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('B')"> B </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('BDS')"> BDSI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNC')"> CNC </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('CNK')"> CNK </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('COLB')"> COLB </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('EWBC')"> EWBC </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('FB')"> FB </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('GPRO')"> GPRO </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HAIN')"> HAIN </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('HEI')"> HEI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('LCI')"> LCI </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('MANU')"> MANU </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('NCLH')"> NCLH </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('RCL')"> RCL </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSN')"> TSN </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('TSO')"> TSO </button> </li>
    <li> <button type="button" onclick="navfunc('WWD')"> WWD </button> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</div>

<!-- CONTENT DIV -->
<div class = 'content'>
<img id='hmap' src = 'AMBA_heatmap.png' alt='AMBA', style="width: 880px; height: 660px;">

</div>

<!-- FOOTER DIV -->
<div class = 'footer'>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```